# Spec file output in Logger File

Tags: scala, logback, scalatest, specs

I have written scala test file using spec, the spec file's output comes console but not in logger file. Though my logback.xml configuration is same for both?

Comment: Can you share your logback.xml, so we can take a look at it, please ?

Comment: I believe that you want to store the results of the test in a file to use in your CI or something similar. You might be interested in http://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/SPECS2-2.4.17/org.specs2.guide.Runners.html and if you are using sbt in http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Testing.html